# Message Handling, unexpected behavior with worker threads

Tags: android, multithreading, message-queue, handler, android-service

I'm taking a stab at a large program with a background Service and I'm implementing a (rather poorly thought out) Message handling procedure using basic Handler objects.  The application has a main menu with buttons which start 6 different activities.

Problem is this: if i start a worker thread which kicks off a query to the database and retrieves some data, and I close the Activity that started the aforementioned worker thread, the Handler in the Activity still tries to run and show a dialog, even though the Activity that created it is now finished (or not in focus).  How can I tell whether the current Activity is in focus before committing any (UI) changes?

I ended up solving the issue by simply putting the 'showDialog()' call in a try statement, but i'd like a more sophisticated solution, as this just seems like the wrong way to do things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sendBroadcast()`, with the `Activity` registering a `BroadcastReceiver` for the broadcast via `registerReceiver()` in `onResume()` and unregistering it in `onPause()`. Then, it will only process the event if it is in the foreground.

Comment: this requires that i completely rewrite my message handling, but that was expected.

Answer (score 0):

Put some flag in  `onPause()` method of activity that starts the thread to indicate that it is not foreground anymore. In `onStart()` reverse the flag.

When it is a time to display dialog, check this flag and only show dialog if activity is running.